# CSS Darken on Hover on white background

Tags: css

**A photo on dark background**
[image]

On Hover (right)

[image]

**A photo on white background**

[image]

On hover (wrong)

[image]

I'd want it be darken on white background also.

**CSS**

```
.photo
  background: no-repeat center center
  background-size: cover
  border-radius: 5px
  width: 100%
  height: 310px 
  position: relative
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)
  &:hover
    background-color: #000
    opacity: 0.5
```

**HTML**

```
<%=link_to p do %>
    <div class="photo smalled" style="background-image: url(<%=backdrop(p, 'w300')%>)">

        <div class="rating text-right">
            <%=starsrating p.rating%>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text-left">
                <h6><%=p.title%></h6>
                <h4>
                    <small>
                        <strong><%=p.nextSchedule.channel.name%></strong>
                         <%=l p.nextSchedule.start, :format => :short%>
                    </small>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of achieving this would be to create a pseudo-element which sits over the top of the `.photo` `<div>`.  It would be transparent at first, then when you hover on the `.photo` `<div>` its background would change to being a translucent black (which could be done by using rgba or by setting the opacity).

```
.photo {
  background: no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 310px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  &:hover {
    &:after {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    }
  }
}
```

**http://jsbin.com/ePiGuha/2/edit**

Of course, this element will cover the elements that sit inside that div.  So, you may need to set those elements to relative and control the z-index.